# php unzip aes256 not working, but unzip with zipcrypto working

Tags: php, laravel-5, unzip

I'm new in PHP programming. I try to unzip a aes256 encrypted file,
but it is not working. I get *Extraction failed (wrong password?)* output on execution.
However, if i use zipcrypto to unzip the file it is successful. I'm using Windows and XAMPP.

This is my PHP code:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_status = $zip->open("jajal.zip");

if ($zip_status == true)
{
    if ($zip->setPassword("t3mp3-g3mbus"))
    {
        if (!$zip->extractTo("img/"))
            echo "Extraction failed (wrong password?)";
    }

    $zip->close();
}
else
{
    die("Failed opening archive: ". @$zip->getStatusString() . " (code: ". $zip_status .")");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without the code, we can't suggest anything about what you are doing wrong.

Comment: i'm so sorry forget include my code @Phylogenesis thank you for correction my question

Comment: Unzipping (= uncompressing) and decrypting (you're referring to AES 256) are two different things. So maybe you should decrypt first, before trying to unzip?

Comment: yes i decrypt my file, first using zipcrypto my program work fine, and then i using AES 256 my program not working, in linux that program can running successly zipcrypto  or  AES 256 no problem, but windows + wampp64 not working

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php, AES-256 is supported “since PHP 7.2.0, PECL zip 1.14.0” - that the case for your local WAMP setup …?